# setting the value for `ORACLE_SID`

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with setting the value for `ORACLE_SID` as the following:

```
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

The problem is I have to set the `ORACLE_SID` every time I login into ubuntu.

How can I keep this value unchanged after I logout ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` to include the line

```
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

EDIT: If you want it available for all users, add the above line to `/etc/environment`